# Error connecting to Cloud SQL if using Self-signed certificate by Google

Tags: google-app-engine, pdo, ssl-certificate, cakephp-3.0, google-cloud-sql

When trying to connect to Cloud SQL using a [Google's self-generated SSL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ssl-instance) certificate we get the following error:

> **Connection to database could not be established: SQLSTATE [HY000] [2002]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change file in: **config/app.php**

```
    ...
    ...

    /**
     * The test connection is used during the test suite.
     */
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'user_name_x',
        'password' => 'pass_x',
        'database' => 'bd_name_x',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'log' => false,

        'flags' => [
           PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY  => CONFIG.'client-key.pem',
           PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => CONFIG.'client-cert.pem',
           PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA   => CONFIG.'server-ca.pem',
           PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
        ],

        //'ssl_key' => CONFIG.'client-key.pem',
        //'ssl_cert' => CONFIG.'client-cert.pem',
        //'ssl_ca' => CONFIG.'server-ca.pem',

        //'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],
    ],
 ],
 ...
 ...
```

---

**Example Test PHP Pure + PDO + SSL Self signed by google:**

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;dbname=db_name_x', 'user_name_x', 'pass_x', array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY   => '/path/full/client-key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT  => '/path/full/client-cert.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA    => '/path/full/server-ca.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT => false
    )
);
$statement = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES;");
var_dump($statement);
$row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($row);
exit();
```